# 'TranslateR' R package is not showing the results of the automated translation

Tags: r, nlp, google-translate

When using the function `translate` from the `translateR` package, the function keeps the source language, i.e. no translation is occuring.

```
library(translateR)
data(enron)
translate(dataset = enron, content.field = 'email', 
                            google.api.key = mygooglekey, source.lang = 'en', 
                            target.lang = 'de')
```

What seems to be the problem? are there any alternatives for doing automated translation in R?

Comment: You need to assign the output of the function to a variable - e.g. `translated_text <- translate(...)`

Comment: thank you Andrew for the comment. Actually, that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was the api key was not activated.
After purchasing credit from the google cloud service the command (below) indeed worked

```
library(translateR)
data(enron)
translateR::translate(dataset = enron, content.field = 'email', 
                            google.api.key = mygooglekey, source.lang = 'en', 
                            target.lang = 'de')
```

If you are facing a problem like this, make sure that your google API key is actually activated.

When you verify your account with the help of paypal account or a credit card, google will give you a 300$ for your trial phase to try the services.

After buying credit or simply using the 300$ you get in your trial phase, the code should run smoothly.

How to activate:
if you don't have a google account, go create one here
https://accounts.google.com/signup

Then sign in to https://console.cloud.google.com/

There, click on try for free.
From there, follow all the verification steps, including adding a credit card or paypal account. This step won't charge you anything, it is only to make sure you are not a bot.

After verification is done. click on the three horizontal lines to the left hand side corner to open up the navigation menu.

There choose API & Services, then choose library.

Search for the service you want, in this case for this question, cloud translation API, and click on it.

Click on Enable.

Then click on credentials on the left hand side pane, then click on create credentials and choose API key.

Summary:
Create a google Cloud account, verify it, enable the api service you want to use, create your own API key. Use that API key to run the service from your R console.